# Xcode no imprime sin salto de linea

Tags: c++, c, xcode

Un código así de simple...
De un dia para otro Xcode no imprime nada sin que le agregue un `\n` al final de la cadena.

Lo mismo pasa en c++, no imprime sin un `endl`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Hola mundo!");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`printf` no escribe en la consola sino en el buffer de salida. Este buffer puede ir dirigido a la consola sí, pero también a un fichero o incluso a una impresora.

Lo importante es que no escribes directamente sobre un dispositivo sino sobre un buffer. Para que la información acabe en el dispositivo de salida es necesario que dicho buffer *vuelque* la información en dicho dispositivo. Mientras eso no suceda el dispositivo de salida no mostrará nada.

¿Cómo se vuelca el contenido del buffer al dispositivo de salida?

La forma más básica es llamar al método `flush` correspondiente. En C++, por ejemplo, `std::endl` acaba llamando a dicho método una vez inserta el salto de línea.

Otra forma suele ser cerrar el buffer. Al hacerlo normalmente se fuerza al volcado de la información que aún no ha sido enviada al dispositivo de salida.

Ahora bien, ¿Por qué XCode ha dejado de funcionar? Técnicamente no es que haya dejado de funcionar sino que su funcionamiento se ha visto modificado. Lo que debía suceder antes es que el IDE cerraba los buffers de salida antes de dar por finalizado el programa. Eso te permitía ver el mensaje justo antes de pulsar una tecla y que la consola se cerrase.

Sin embargo tiene pinta de que ahora el programa no cierra dichos buffers hasta que el programa finaliza físicamente. El efecto es que aunque el mensaje se muestre por la consola, el tiempo de impresión sea tan efímero que al usuario le parezca que no se ha mostrado nada. Puedes probar a ejecutar el programa desde una consola abierta por tí y verás como el mensaje sí que se muestra (o se debería mostrar).

Answer (score 0):

Esto se resolvió en la version 8.3.2. Es el quinto punto[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]